# Is there a way to construct a HashSet with initializator function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

To read Stars from a file in the [Facebook Hacker Cup's 2016](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problem/910374079035613/) Boomerang Constelations problem, following extension function can be defined:

```
fun BufferedReader.readStars(n: Int): Set<Star> {
    return Array(n) {
        val (l1, l2) = readLine().split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
        Star(l1, l2)
    }.toHashSet()
}
```

Code is compact but the values are first read into an array and then converted to a `HashSet`. Is there a way to directly initialize a `HashSet` with the size of `n` and initializator function in Kotlin?

**UPDATE:** Is there an **existing** way in standard Kotlin libs?

Comment: It seems like you are asking an XY question (http://xyproblem.info/).  Would you rather ask how to do your function `readStars` in the most efficient manner?

Comment: I answered what your question appears to be (X) instead of `HashSet` (Y), see new answer below.

Comment: Did you try to create a `HashSet` yourself?  Like "val mySet = HashSet<Star>(...)` ?  If so, you would already know how to create a `HashSet`.    You didn't show what you already tried in your question, so it is confusing because anyone can create a `HashSet` if they want.  Without Kotlin stdlib.  The stdlib would only add a helper function to make it more consistent with Kotlin style, but it doesn't add `HashSet` to available options.

Comment: Your `HashSet` question can be solved by yourself by reading https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html  and trying a few experiments with the constructors of `HashSet` ... it is not a good SO question.  The other "how do I write this more efficient" would not be down voted.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Thank you for putting so much energy into your answers and comments - they contain plenty of useful information. Maybe the what-is-the-best-way-to-read-stars question would have been a better one however I was really interested in a nice, compact and effective way to create a HashSet *with Kotlin* because I'm learning it, not due to poor performance in the specific case. Just looking into kotlin/collections or constructors of HashSet, I couldn't have come up to the solution using "apply()" provided by KirillRakhman. I'll try my best to formulate better questions in the future.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use `apply` to initialize objects in-place:

```
HashSet<Star>(n).apply {
    repeat(n) {
        val (l1, l2) = readLine()!!.split(' ').map { it.toInt() }
        put(Star(l1, l2))
    }
}
```

If that's too inconvenient too type every time, write an extension function:

```
inline fun <T> createHashSet(n : Int, crossinline fn: (Int) -> T) = HashSet<T>(n).apply {
    repeat(n) { add(fn(it)) }
}
```

Usage:

```
createHashSet<Star>(n) {
    val (l1, l2) = readLine()!!.split(' ').map { it.toInt() }
    Star(l1, l2)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is a java class so you can only initialize it in a way provided by JDK.

While there's **no helper method in Kotlin runtime** it's easy to write it yourself like so:

```
public fun <T> hashSetOf(size: Int, initializer: (Int) -> T): HashSet<T> {
    val result = HashSet<T>(size)
    0.rangeTo(size - 1).forEach {
        result.add(initializer(it))
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: You can even name your function "HashSet" so it would look like a normal constructor of the HashSet. I wanted to know if there is something already present in the standard kotlin libs, or maybe some different approach altogether.

Comment: @VilmantasBaranauskas it isn't advised to try and hide a constructor with an extension function.

Comment: @miensol your code shouldn't assume that the initial capacity of the HashSet will be the same as the items loaded.  Most times they would not be for optimal performance.  Plus your implementation isn't useable from the `readStars` method (how would you integrate that without holding the values in something before, which is already the problem)

Comment: @JaysonMinard I've only given answer to the following questions "Is there a way to directly initialize a HashSet with the size of n and initializator function in Kotlin?" and "Is there an existing way in standard Kotlin libs?". It may be the XY question/problem though.

Answer (score 1):

As @miensol has pointed out [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) initialization is limited to the constructors made available by the JDK. Kotlin has added a [`hashSetOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-set-of.html) function which initializes an empty `HashSet` and then adds the specified elements to it.

To avoid first reading the values into an array you can use a [`kotlin.Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-sequence/) who's "values are evaluated lazily":

```kotlin
fun BufferedReader.readStars(n: Int): Set<Star> {
    return lineSequence().take(n).map {
        val (l1, l2) = it.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
        Star(l1, l2)
    }.toHashSet()
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Your `splitToSequence()` that then does `take(2)` and does `toList()` doesn't really save anything in the end.  Results in the same work and requires allocation of a Sequence, Iterator for the Sequence, a Take class from the Sequence, and then a List.  So that is more allocations in the end.  The version that uses an iterator is better, but then it allocates a class as the Iterator so doesn't necessarily save anything again.   You just change what is allocated, and maybe create more.

Comment: @JaysonMinard You may be right. I haven't compared the overhead between a Kotlin Sequence and Lists but from what I can tell in the first solution `split` creates a list and then `map` creates another list. In the second solution `splitToSequence` creates a lazily evaluated `iterator` and then a list (so *if* a sequence has less overhead then a list then this is a win). In the `iterator` solutions no list is ever made (so again *if* a sequence has less overhead then a list then this is another win). I suppose for small lists you are absolutely right: use a list. I will update. Thank you.

Comment: The CPU cache will make the copy of the lists very cheap.  Lazy is not always cheaper for small things.   `split(char)` makes a sequence, allocates an anonymous `Iterable` which is then `map` into a `List`.  `splitToSequence(char)` makes a sequence, and then when you `map` tacks an instance of `TransformingSequence` which then creates anonymous instance of `Iterator` which is then `toList`.  So you do everything the other version does +1 other allocation.  And really, small things are better as copied, really large things maybe not.  Depends on how close in time the copy is, the CPU cache,...

Comment: So Sequence mislead you into a less performant option.  There is a reason Kotlin defaults to making copies of collections a lot, because most cases it does not matter and performs as well or better than lazy eval.  You should assume copy is fine until you have indication it isn't.  Like size vs. memory, slowness shown to be in the copying, etc.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Yep. That makes sense. Thanks. FYI: [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/split.html) returns `List<String>` not `Sequence<String>`.

Comment: I didn't say `split` returns a `Sequence`, internally the code within `split` makes a `Sequence` which ...(the rest of my paragraph)

Comment: (and really in the scheme of this code, assuming he isn't reading a billion stars from the file, not sure this level of optimization even matters)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking an XY question (http://xyproblem.info/).  You really want to know how to write `readStars` in the most efficient way, but instead you ask about `HashSet`.  I think @mfulton26 answers your question as well depending on what is being asked.

**Here is the answer for "how do I write this in the most efficient way:"**

You have two options.  First, a version that auto-closes the stream at the end:

```
fun BufferedReader.readStars(n: Int): Set<Star> {
    return use {
        lineSequence().map { line ->
            val idx = line.indexOf(' ')
            Star(line.substring(0, idx).toInt(), line.substring(idx + 1).toInt())
        }.toSet()
    }
}
```

And second, a version that does not:

```
fun BufferedReader.readStars(n: Int): Set<Star> {
    return lineSequence().map { line ->
            val idx = line.indexOf(' ')
            Star(line.substring(0, idx).toInt(), line.substring(idx+1).toInt())
        }.toSet()
}
```

Neither version creates an array, neither do they make copies of data.  They stream the data through a sequence which creates the Set and fills it directly.

**Other notes**

No need to use split if you are really concerned about allocations and performance.  Just use `indexOf(char)` and split the string yourself using `substring`.

If you do a split, then please use `split(char)` not `split(String)` when you are looking to split on a `char`

Comment: these two last charapters a kind of uncalled for. I suggest changing them into a link to the docs and a smily

Comment: I deleted the last HashSet part because I already down voted the question asking how to create a HashSet which is a bad question for SO.  No need to repeat it here in the answer.

Comment: "A call to substring does not copy the internal array, but shares it and is very efficient." — It isn't so anymore starting from Java 7