# Generic bounds on a single constructor

Tags: generics, constructor, kotlin

Let's say I have a generic class:

```
class OrderedArray<T>(
    private val items: Array<T>,
    private val comparator: Comparator<in T>
) {
    constructor(items: Array<T>) : this(items, naturalOrder<T>())
}
```

Of course this code does not compile as `T` is not necessarily comparable. Is there a language construct available which bounds the generic parameter of a type on a constructor? How could I allow to construct an instance of my class without explicitly passing the comparator when a natural ordering is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to introduce a generic bound on a constructor because constructors don't have their own generic parameters, they can only use the class parameters.

Consider the following workarounds:

- One solution is to make a subclass with the generic bound and use it:

  ```
  class NaturallyOrderedArray<T: Comparable<T>>(items: Array<T>) 
      : OrderedArray<T>(items, naturalOrder<T>())
  ```

  But it looks clumsy (*write a class just to override a generic bound and introduce another constructor?!*) and requires the parent class to be `open` or at least `sealed`.
- You can make a factory function with the desired generic bound:

  ```
  fun <T: Comparable<T>> naturallyOrderedArray(items: Array<T>) = 
      OrderedArray(items, naturalOrder<T>())
  ```

  You might make the function mimic a constructor so that it would be called like `OrderedArray(items)`, but [it's better to keep to consistent naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751897/is-naming-a-function-same-as-an-existing-class-should-be-avoided-in-kotlin-why) that would also hint that the natural order is used.

Answer (score 1):

I would write strait-forwardly:

```
class OrderedArray<T: Comparable<T>>(
    private val items: Array<T>,
    private val comparator: Comparator<in T> = naturalOrder<T>())
```

Does it solve the problem? If not, what are the limitations for your case?

Comment: The thing is that I would like my class to work with non-comparable T-s as well. Of course an explicit comparator must be provided in those cases.