# Context with programmatically overridden settings

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-context, android-styles

I'd like to create a bunch of `View`s with a context that is based on some style, but also some dynamically calculated overrides. I'd like to create a `Context` that encapsulates all that, so that I can pass that to various different `View` constructors.

To make my question more complete, without the dynamic part, I'd be using a `ContextThemeWrapper` like this:

```
// in my onCreate
Context styling = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.TextBase_OutputText);
View v1 = TextView(styling);
View v2 = Button(styling);
// and so on
```

But I'd instead like to do this:

```
// in onCreate
Context styling = new ContextWrapperThatImLookingFor(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.TextBase_OutputText));
styling.addOverride(textColor, computeForegroundColorDynamically()); // ???
View v1 = TextView(styling);
// and so on
```

How do I achieve this?

(**note** that this question is about the Android platform, not about any Kotlin or Java language feature as a commenter suggested -- `ContextWrapperThatImLookingFor` would be a simple subclass of `Context` that I can add overrides to that are then applied to `View`s created subsequently with that context)

Comment: You cannot have `constructors` as extensions for any class as of yet in kotlin check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582809/is-it-possible-to-create-extension-constructors-in-kotlin

Comment: No this is not about any Kotlin language feature. The question would work just as well with Java or any other language. The question is about the Android platform, and how I can make a `Context` which uses a style plus programmatic overrides.