# Type aliases with extension functions as a constructor, good practice?

Tags: kotlin, type-alias

So I really like using type aliases in Kotlin, but I am wondering if my approach to it is considered to be bad, indifferent or good practice. See the following:

```
typealias MyAlias = Map<String, String>

fun MyAlias() : MyAlias = emptyMap()

fun MyAlias(vararg mapEntries: Pair<String, String>) : MyAlias = {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>
    mapEntries.forEach{map[it.first] = it.second]}
    return map
}
```

Thoughts?
(May be a question subject to opinions, but I have seen some good discussions in the past with very helpful pointers, so I am hoping this will be one of those)

Comment: I'd say indifferent (except it should just be `= mutableMapOf(*mapEntries)`).

Comment: Where are the extension functions mentioned in the title?  I see only top-level functions, not extending anything.

Comment: @gidds The extension functions are constructors in this case.

Comment: @k88 They're functions, but they're not extending anything.  An [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) has the receiver type and a dot before the function name.

Comment: You're right, but this mimics a constructor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582809/is-it-possible-to-create-extension-constructors-in-kotlin/46582945#46582945