# Can I add companion extension without first having companion object within a class?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension, kotlin-companion

For the below code, I can add `invoke` extension to the `Companion`

```
operator fun MyValue.Companion.invoke(value: Int) =
    MyValue(value.toString())

class MyValue(private val value: String) {
    companion object
    fun print() = println("value = $value")
}
```

This enable me to call something as below

```
MyValue(1).print()
```

But as you see originally `MyValue` don't need the `companion object`.

I wonder if `MyValue` is without the `companion object`, i.e.

```
class MyValue(private val value: String) {
    fun print() = println("value = $value")
}
```

Is it possible for me to still create a Companion extension function? e.g.

```
operator fun MyValue.Companion.invoke(value: Int) =
    MyValue(value.toString())
```

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to create extension constructors in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582809/is-it-possible-to-create-extension-constructors-in-kotlin)

Comment: Not possible. Think about the implementation - companion objects cannot be added *retroactively* to already compiled classes, whenever the compiler sees that you want to extend `Something.Companion`.

Comment: A similar feature is being prototyped https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968

Answer (score 0):

You can add a secondary constructor to your class that accept an Int,

```
class MyValue(private val value: String) {
    constructor(value: Int) : this(value.toString())

    fun print() = println("value = $value")
}
```

Now you can call both, `MyValue("10").print()` and `MyValue(10).print()`

Comment: I'm assuming I don't have access to the `MyValue` class, hence needing the extension function. I can also use `fun MyValue(value: Int) = MyValue(value.toString())`, but I want to see if we can extend a Companion function without originally having Companion within.

Comment: I don't think that so, `print` function requires `value` so this is not possible without companion object or extension function.